# IOS Insert Multiple Sections on load more

Tags: ios, uitableview, infinite-scroll, sections

Having a hard time figuring out how to add additional sections to my tableview when a user reaches the end of the currently loaded content. My table is setup in such a way that each piece of content is givien a section in the tableview and I have no clue how to go about adding say 50 new section to my table using a library like this :

https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

```
- (void)insertRowAtBottom {
    __weak SVViewController *weakSelf = self;

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
        [weakSelf.dataSource addObject:[weakSelf.dataSource.lastObject dateByAddingTimeInterval:-90]];
        [weakSelf.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:weakSelf.dataSource.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];

        [weakSelf.tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of I made my array Mutable so that I can just add objects to it. Then you also have to reload the tableview because you are changing the number of `myArray.count` I looked up what an `NSIndexSet` was and I made one for my array so I could set new sections for my tableview (add on the bottom or top) this is the full "block of code" that I used.

```
//Reload the tableview and update the array count
[self.tableView reloadData];
//Start the update
            [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
//Created the NSIndexSet to go into the next method
            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [self.games indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
            }];
//Inserting the new sections
            [weakSelf.tableView insertSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
            //Stop the Animation
            [weakSelf.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
```

If you do not reload the tableview your tableview **WILL NOT** update. It may even crash because there is some weird error that appears.